# Recursion (Javascript) - does not exit recursion out of "IF" statement

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree

I am learning recursion in Javascript and here's what I got so far. This function traverses the tree and finds an object with the matching name propertity. As the start needs to be set as the root, I created a recursion to use the root as the starting point.

The first if statement in the for loop halfway should return the match. I've debugged pieces of it in the console so I know that the return is not working for whatever reason that I am not aware of (any insight would be great for learning purposes!).

The set console logs as I expect it to, the boolean check shows that a match does happen, but still getting undefined at the end!

```
findInTree(name) {
    let start = this.first();   //root object of the tree

    function findName (start, name) {
      if (start.name === name) {
        return start;
      } else {
        for (let set of start.offspring) {
          if (set.name === name) {
            console.log(set);   // returns the correct set!
            console.log(set.name === name)  //returns true;
            return set;
          } else {
            findName(set, name);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return findName(start, name);
  }
// returns undefined...
```

Answer (score 0):

You only want to return from your loop if the recursion found what you're looking for. Otherwise you want to keep looping. You can test the result and decide whether to return:

```js
let obj = {
    first: {
        name: "test",
        offspring:[
            {name: "test1", offspring:[]},
            {name: "test2", offspring:[{name:"test21", offspring:[]}]},
            {name: "test3", offspring:[
                {name: "test31", offspring:[]}
            ]},
        ]
    },
    findInTree(name) {
    let start = this.first;   //root object of the tree

    function findName (start, name) {
      if (start.name === name) {
        return start;
      } else {
        for (let set of start.offspring) {
          if (set.name === name) {
            console.log(set);   // returns the correct set!
            console.log(set.name === name)  //returns true;
            return set;
          } else {
            let found = findName(set, name); // only return if you've found 
            if (found) return found          // what you're looking for
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return findName(start, name);
  }
}
console.log(obj.findInTree("test31"))
```

Comment: Hmm... I think I kind of get it, but just for clarification, is there a reason why the return doesn't happen in the if statement "(set.name === name)"? My understanding was that if one of the recursions found a match, they would exit the loop and return the match using the "if/else". Is there a reason why this isn't the case? And also thank you for taking the time to review the code, I'll definitely look into it in detail for a better understanding.

Comment: So if you trace it though the tree above what happens is it calls `findName()` on the first offspring where the name doesn't exit. So that function doesn't return `start` because the condition doesn't match, and there's no children so it never runs the loop. The result is that it returns undefined. And returning from a for loop stops the loop and returns from the function before you get a chance to loop to the one containing what you want.

Comment: Oh! I see it now, wow. Thanks so much for the explanation Mark! Placement of the return, I'll keep an eye out for that moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

Do you think this will work? Move the recursion call out of the for loop. only if the match is not found in the for loop, you call the function findName. If possible, can you put your code in jsfiddle or somewhere so that I can take a look.

```
    findInTree(name) {
    let start = this.first();   //root object of the tree

    function findName (start, name) {
      if (start.name === name) {
        return start;
      } else {

        for (let set of start.offspring) {
          if (set.name === name) {
            console.log(set);   // returns the correct set!
            console.log(set.name === name)  //returns true;
            return set;
          }
        }
       return findName(set, name);   //if the match is not found in the forloop, we call findname

      }
    }
    return findName(start, name); 
}
```

Comment: Just did a test run and unfortunately doesn't seem to work. Here's the jsfiddle link ! https://jsfiddle.net/4g6r5bz7/

Comment: Most of your code looks good. I think you just need to add this  to check whether match is undefined or not. 

let matchFound = findName(set, name);
            if(matchFound)
                return matchFound;





I just saw that from the previous reply that you have already found the solution. Good to know.

Comment: Thank you for reviewing it! Yes, been looking into it to get a better understanding of how the matches take place in recursions, brushing up on how functions and loops react to returns!